# Python Regex replace part of string

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I am trying to replace a specific part of my string. Everytime I have a backslash, followed by a capital letter, I want the backslash to be replaced with a tab. Like in this case:

```
Hello/My daugher/son
```

The output should look like

```
Hello    My daugher/son
```

I have tried to use re.sub():

```
for x in a:
    x = re.sub('\/[A-Z]', '\t[A-Z]', x)
```

But then my output changes into:

```
Hello    [A-Z]y daugher/son
```

Which is really not what I want. Is there a better way to tackle this, maybe not in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `/(?=[A-Z])` with `\t`. Notice in Python you don't need to escape `/` as `\/`

Check this Python code,

```
import re 

s = 'Hello/My daugher/son'
print(re.sub(r'/(?=[A-Z])',r'\t',s))
```

Prints,

```
Hello   My daugher/son
```

Alternatively, following the way you were trying to replace, you need to capture the capital letter in a group using `/([A-Z])` regex and then replace it with `\t\1` to restore what got captured in group1. Check this Python codes,

```
import re 

s = 'Hello/My daugher/son'
print(re.sub(r'/([A-Z])',r'\t\1',s))
```

Again prints,

```
Hello   My daugher/son
```